# Error in the two-stroke percentage calculation with two different codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

.
Hello, everyone,

My name is Elizabeth, I'm new to javascript programming so please don't be too hard on me.

I have a problem when calculating percentages of increase or decrease with two different javascript functions. The thing is that they throw different percentages at me and I really don't know what's wrong and why they're throwing different numbers at me.

```
  let timein = "00:42:02"; 
  let timeoutt = "00:02:32";
```

With this function I'm sure 99% is throwing me the right percentage which would be 6%.

```
 function timestamp_to_seconds(timestamp) {
        var [hours, minutes, seconds] = timestamp.split(':').map((t) => parseInt(t, 10));
        return seconds + 60 * minutes + 60 * 60 * hours;
    }

var original_seconds = timestamp_to_seconds(timein);
var duration_seconds = timestamp_to_seconds(timeoutt);
var new_seconds = original_seconds + duration_seconds;
var ratio = new_seconds / original_seconds;
var numero = Math.floor(ratio * 100);
var stringNumero = numero.toString();
var cadena_final = stringNumero.slice(1, 23);
```

**cadena_final is = 6%**

Now this is the function that's not throwing me the right percentage that would be the top one and I don't know why.

```
        const ONE_DAY = 8.64e7; // 86400000 millis
        // let time = calculo;
        let time = "00:42:02"; // the time over which you want to increase the percentage  %
        let hoy = new Date();

        hoy.setHours(time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1], time.split(":")[2]); // Establece el tiempo de lo que vamos a buscar %

        let manana = new Date(Date.now() + ONE_DAY).setHours("0", "0", "0");
        let porcent = ((manana - hoy) / ONE_DAY * 100).toFixed("2") + "%";

        // This is to increase or decrease
        const HOUR = 3.6e6; // 360000
        const MINUTE = 6e4; // 60000
        const SECOND = 1e3; // 1000
        let incPercent = 0.06; //This would be the percentage that would increase. I've put in a 6% increase
        let increased = new Date(hoy.getTime() + (incPercent * HOUR));

        var fecha = increased;
        var hora = fecha.getHours();
        var minuto = fecha.getMinutes();
        var segundo = fecha.getSeconds();

        if (hora < 10) {
            hora = "0" + hora;
        }
        if (minuto < 10) {
            minuto = "0" + minuto;
        }
        if (segundo < 10) {
            segundo = "0" + segundo;
        }
        var horita = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;
```

**horita  is = 00:45:38 for a 6% increase**

I've set a 06% increase and it increases me to 00:45:38 which would be 
00:03:36 rise time over 00:42:02.

Therefore it has incorrectly increased the % of time.

In the first function it increases by 6% which would be 02:31:00
And in this function a 6% increase would be 00:03:36

What am I doing wrong for the second function to miscalculate the percentage increase?

Thank you very much in advance to all and I feel my ignorance, a greeting

Elizabeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a programming issue. It's logic.

In the first part, you calculated the ratio between `timein` and `timein + timeout` in seconds **base on "00:00:00"**.

But in the second part, you created an instance that represents a single moment in time which is **based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC**. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

**The comparing benchmark is totally different.**

Change it to the same benchmark and it would be correct.

```js
let timein = "00:42:02";
let timeoutt = "00:02:32"; // timeout, a typo here?

function timestamp_to_seconds(timestamp) {
  var [hours, minutes, seconds] = timestamp.split(':').map((t) => parseInt(t, 10));
  return seconds + 60 * minutes + 60 * 60 * hours;
}

let start = new Date()
start.setHours(timein.split(":")[0], timein.split(":")[1], timein.split(":")[2], 0);

var duration_seconds = timestamp_to_seconds(timeoutt) * 1000;
var end = new Date(start.getTime() + duration_seconds);
var ratio = end.getTime() / start.getTime();
console.log('ratio:', ratio);

let time = "00:42:02";
let hoy = new Date();

hoy.setHours(time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1], time.split(":")[2], 0);

const HOUR = 3.6e6; // 360000 <-miss a zero here BTW

let increased = new Date(hoy.getTime() * ratio);
var fecha = increased;
var hora = fecha.getHours();
var minuto = fecha.getMinutes();
var segundo = fecha.getSeconds();

if (hora < 10) {
  hora = "0" + hora;
}
if (minuto < 10) {
  minuto = "0" + minuto;
}
if (segundo < 10) {
  segundo = "0" + segundo;
}
var horita = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;

;
(function() {
  console.log('expect: 00:44:34')
  console.log('result:', horita)
})();
```

Edit:

As per comment, here's another way using the increases ratio.

And you should know that the increase ratio is a percentage which shows the increase ratio from `timein` to `timein+timeout`.

So incPercent is **nothing to do with HOUR**.

If doing like what you did above, it means the increase from `timein` to `timein+timeout` equals to `HOUR*6%`, which is incorrect.

```js
let timein = "00:42:02";
let timeoutt = "00:02:32";

function timestamp_to_seconds(timestamp) {
  var [hours, minutes, seconds] = timestamp.split(':').map((t) => parseInt(t, 10));
  return seconds + 60 * minutes + 60 * 60 * hours;
}

// let us skip something...

var ratio = 0.06;

console.log('ratio:', ratio);

let time = "00:42:02";
let timeInSecond = timestamp_to_seconds(time);

let increased = timeInSecond * (1 + ratio);

const Hour = 3600; // in second
const Minute = 60; // in second

var fecha = increased;
var hora = Math.floor(fecha/3600);
var minuto = Math.floor(fecha%3600/60);
var segundo = Math.floor(fecha%3600%60);

if (hora < 10) {
  hora = "0" + hora;
}
if (minuto < 10) {
  minuto = "0" + minuto;
}
if (segundo < 10) {
  segundo = "0" + segundo;
}
var horita = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;

;
(function() {
  console.log('expect: 00:44:34')
  console.log('result:', horita)
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I appreciate it. I appreciate it. The function works now, but the problem is that I can no longer increase by a percentage. I mean, the calculation does it well for me, but I can't assign the % increase to get the right result. In other words, before with the incPercent variable I could calculate the percentage although I was not doing it correctly. This is the complete function I had done

Answer (score 0):

```
PorcenNumermas ='6.00'; //Percentage to be increased in time
function Percentma() {
    var checkedNew = PorcenNumermas.split(".");
    uno = checkedNew[0];
    dos = checkedNew[1];
    //var tres = checkedNew[2];


    if (dos === undefined) {

        if (uno !== 10) { //If it's a 10, remove two zeros.

            incPercent = 0 + "." + 10;
        } else {
            //   let coman = 0.0;
            //  let incPercent = coman.concat(uno);
            incPercent = 0 + "." + 0 + uno; // This would be the percentage
        }
    } else {
        // let coman = 0.0;
        //  let incPercent = coman.concat(uno);
        incPercent = 0 + "." + 0 + uno + dos;  // This would be the percentage if 0 of the integers is not defined
    }

    const ONE_DAY = 8.64e7; // 86400000 milisegundos
    // let time = calculo;
    let time = '00:42:02'; // The time where you are looking %
    let hoy = new Date();

    hoy.setHours(time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1], time.split(":")[2]); // Sets the time of what we are going to look for %

    let manana = new Date(Date.now() + ONE_DAY).setHours("0", "0", "0");
    let porcent = ((manana - hoy) / ONE_DAY * 100).toFixed("2") + "%";

    // 
    const HOUR = 3.6e6; // 360000
    const MINUTE = 6e4; // 60000
    const SECOND = 1e3; // 1000
    //incPercent = 0.03; // Here we select the % of increase if we hadn't written it manually in the upper variable

    let increased = new Date(hoy.getTime() + (incPercent * HOUR));


    var fecha = increased;
    var hora = fecha.getHours();
    var minuto = fecha.getMinutes();
    var segundo = fecha.getSeconds();

    if (hora < 10) {
        hora = "0" + hora;
    }
    if (minuto < 10) {
        minuto = "0" + minuto;
    }
    if (segundo < 10) {
        segundo = "0" + segundo;
    }
    var horita = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;


    console.log('result:', horita)
}
;
Percentma();
```

Here I increase by 6% to 00:42:02 and as a result he throws me incorrectly 00:45:38. That's what I was saying earlier, you really should throw me 00:44:34. Before I forgot to mention and put in the percentage option which is the one I needed. Thank you very much in advance